# Как посчитать сложный процент?

Tags: математика

Когда мы имеем:

100 (например тело вклада, первоначальный взнос)
2% (процент за одну единицу времени, например за день) - номинальная процентная ставка.

Нужна формула вот сюда
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `D*1.02^E`, `^` — возвещение в степень.

Comment: А "F" куда? Выпала из формулы

Comment: А что такое F. В задаче про F ничего не сказано.